# call stored procedure from another database in sql azure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have 2 databases db1 and db2 in azure.And db1 is having stored procedure stored_p1,db2 is having stored procedure stored_p2.
I need to call stored_p1 from stored_p2.
For calling table from another database i have used external tables.
for storedprocedure, do i need to use anything like external table

Answer (score 2):

This seems to require `elastic` database queries, potentially with the `SP_ EXECUTE_FANOUT` command.

> Remote stored procedure calls or remote functions invocations that use
>   sp_execute_fanout can now use parameters similar to sp_executesql.

[The documntation is here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/)

[This may also help](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/)

Options without *sharding* are still apparently "in the works" last I heard.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it was still relevant to me.  Here is my solution (in my case I am connecting between two different database servers):

1. In DB2, create the credential you will use to connect to DB1:

```
    CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL DB1Credential
    WITH IDENTITY = 'DB1_User',
    SECRET = 'DB1_Password';
```

2. In DB2, create the external datasource using your new credential:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE DB1Server WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = 'your-db1-server-reference',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'db1',
    CREDENTIAL = DB1Credential,
    ) ;
```

3. Execute your remote procedure by naming your remote data source:

```
    EXEC sp_execute_remote
    N'DB1Server',  
    N'stored_p1'
```

Parameters can also be included as defined here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

Answer (score 1):

This requires elastic database queries. Consider using the cross-database functionality documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-vertical-partitioning/.

It also provides for a function called sp_execute_remote which takes a shardmap name and a T-SQL query as its input.